# Load the ftplugin folder via janus

Tags: vim, macvim, janus, pathogen

I posted an issue at github about this as well, but I figured this would also be a good spot to ask:

Does anyone know how to accomplish this functionality? I've been trying for the past couple of days to figure this out all to no avail aside from putting directly into my `~/.vim/` folder.

I'm trying to install the [jslint](https://github.com/hallettj/jslint.vim) `ftplugin` to give me error highlighting while eding javascript files.  I have tried all the following combinations to try and get this ftplugin to work within the contexts of janus:

```
~/.janus/langs/javascript/ftplugin/jslint/
~/.janus/ftplugin/javascript/jslint/
~/.vim/janus/vim/langs/javascript/ftplugin/jslint/
~/.vim/janus/ftplugin/javascript/jslint/
```

All of those above fail to recognize this `ftplugin`.  The only one that works is this:

```
~/.vim/ftplugin/javascript/jslint/
```

but that is not ideal since this is not core to janus.  Any ideas on where this folder (or any other `ftplugin` folders for that matter) can be put so macvim to recognize this functionality?

Comment: The github issue dtan created for this is here: https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/357

Comment: ha.  thanks alex.  i can't remember what i did b/c 1) it's been a while and 2) i started using sublime text 2.  Even though sublime text 2 uses vi commands, it's been a good compromise for my particular workflow/needs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to put it in

```
~/.janus/jslint/ftplugin/javascript/jslint.vim
```

Each folder inside the .janus should have the same file structure as a normal .vim folder. (So the ~/.janus/jslint folder is equivalent to .vim)

---

Note janus made this task really hard. Using plugin distributions like janus might lead to easy set up in the beginning but changing them or debugging them will be hard. You should set up your vim environment the way you want so that you know everything in it. This will lead to easier maintenance later on in life. And you will know how to use everything because everything was installed one at a time instead of all at once.